# Automated login from C# Using Post in WPF

Tags: c#, cefsharp, pinterest

I've been trying to write an app to use OAUTH method with pInterest to Upload new pins automatically and have been trying to find the best way of doing this.

So Far i've got a working example going where in my WPF app in C# i can get the login details using a RestAPI Get Method to get the login URL for the pInterest user and once logged it my app will hit tab twice then enter to give permission from pInterest.

The Method i've got working involves -

1. Using .NET 4.6.2 or later getting WebView UI WPF controls from nuget
2. Using RestAPI Get Method to get the URL of the app accept page
3. Using the output of step 2 in a webview component to let IE login and display the App Accept Page ( IE having username / password set up already)
4. OnNavigateComplete once the URL has "/api.pinterest.com/oauth" using SendKeys.SendWait from Winforms to send Tab, Tab , Enter
5. Once Navigate completes grab the URL if its got "state" & "code" in the URL then close the form.

I'm looking to see if there is a better way of doing this i've tried CefSharp but the GetAuthorizeCreditials does not fire off when i implement my own IResponseHandler as its a Post Submit button and i've tried to use javascript code from C# passed in via cefSharp but i couldnt get it to work

Comment: Please update your question to include which version of `CefSharp` you are using and show the code you've tried that is not working. `GetAuthCredentials` is only called when a page requests auth at the network layer, http basic auth, proxy auth, ftp auth etc.

Comment: WPF V69 , the page is the login page for pInterest

Comment: I know nothing about `pintrest`. Please post the code you've tried already.

Comment: MyChromeWebBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser();
            MainGrid.Children.Add(MyChromeWebBrowser);
            MyChromeWebBrowser.RequestHandler = new MyResponseHandler("*****@?????.net", "*****");
            MyChromeWebBrowser.IsBrowserInitializedChanged += OnIsBrowserInitializedChanged;

Comment: this never fires. - > 
        public bool GetAuthCredentials(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, bool isProxy, string host, int port, string realm, string scheme, IAuthCallback callback)
        {
            callback.Continue(user, pass);
            return true;
        }

Comment: Please don't post code in the comments, too hard to read. As I've already said `GetAuthCredentials` is only used for network layer auth, if `pintrest` presents a web page for login then the method is irellivent

Comment: ` i've tried to use javascript code from C# passed in via cefSharp` where is your javascript code? This is likely to be the approach you'll need to take.